# Android load application component from external APK in the SD card

Tags: android

I successfully loaded a fragment from the external APK and then i added the fragment in the activity and it is working fine. but i am facing one issue when android system kills my application when it is in background at that when i launch the application from the home screen or Recent app my application crash because android system auto create that fragment for my application but unable to find the same. Any help to resolve this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to launch app as Fresh when you launch app from home?

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working, will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: How is it possible? but we also get same problem when user launch the application from recent app.